# How to use output parameter and select query result of a sql server stored procedure in ado.net?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, ado.net

Hi I want to get the value of output parameter and as well as the result set of select query. 
I used `ExecuteNonQuery`, it gives proper value for output parameter. 
I used `ExecuteReader` it does not give proper value for output parameter but it gives proper value for select query.  
So what should I use to get both the results.

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[XYZ] 
(  
 @szUserName varchar(50),  
 @iOutDistinceBankCount int out
)  
AS  
BEGIN  
declare @iCountDistinctBanks int;
set @iCountDistinctBanks = (select count (distinct a.DCC_BANK_ID )
 from DEF a with(nolock)
join ABC b with(nolock) on
 a.ROLEID = b.ROLEID
where b.USERNAME = @szUserName and b.STATUS_ID = 2)

if ((@iCountDistinctBanks > 1) or (@iCountDistinctBanks = 0))
    begin
        set @iOutDistinceBankCount = @iCountDistinctBanks 
    end

else
    begin
        set @iOutDistinceBankCount = 1;
            select a.DCC_BANK_ID as DCC_BANK_ID
            from DEF a with(nolock)
            join ABC b with(nolock) on
            a.ROLEID = b.ROLEID
            where b.USERNAME = @szUserName and b.STATUS_ID = 2
    end

END
```

This is my C# Code.

```
Int32 i32DistinctDCCBankCount = -1;
            Int64 i64BankStaticID = -1;
            InitDB();
            m_command = new SqlCommand("DCC_spUIDCCBankIdAccordingUser", m_con);
            m_command.Parameters.Add("@szUserName", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = MerchantName;

            SqlParameter output = new SqlParameter("@iOutDistinceBankCount", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
            output.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
            m_command.Parameters.Add(output);

            m_command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            m_con.Open();
           // m_reader = m_command.ExecuteReader();
            m_command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            i32DistinctDCCBankCount = Convert.ToInt32(m_command.Parameters["@iOutDistinceBankCount"].Value);


                    if (i32DistinctDCCBankCount == 0)
                    {
                        iDistinctDCCBankCount = 0;
                        return i32DistinctDCCBankCount;
                    }
                    else if (i32DistinctDCCBankCount > 1)
                    {
                        iDistinctDCCBankCount = i32DistinctDCCBankCount;
                        return -2;
                    }
                    else if (i32DistinctDCCBankCount == 1)
                    {
                        i64BankStaticID = Convert.ToInt64(m_reader["DCC_BANK_ID"]);
                        iDistinctDCCBankCount = i32DistinctDCCBankCount;
                        return i64BankStaticID;
                    }


            iDistinctDCCBankCount = 0;
            return 0;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This same query can be executed directly with the **Command.ExecuteReader** (or **ExecuteNonQuery** if you don't have a rowset to process),


 but there are several other steps you'll need to take to process the returned values. Remember, you'll have to complete processing for all rowsets *before* attempting to capture the Return value or *OUTPUT* parameters. The following code shows how to use the ExecuteReader and a loop to process the rowsets, and then capture the Return value and *OUTPUT* parameters. You'll find that *OUTPUT* parameters (even a lot of them) can be handled far faster than even a single row of data returned by a **SELECT**.

here is example

```
    With cmd.Parameters
        cn.Open()
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
        ' Process rowset(s)
        bolEOF = dr.Read
        Do
            Do While bolEOF = True
                ' Process rows
                bolEOF = dr.Read()
            Loop
        Loop While dr.NextResult = True
        cmd.Cancel()
// you need to close dataReader first
        dr.Close()


        Debug.WriteLine("@iOutDistinceBankCount:" & _
            .Item("@iOutDistinceBankCount").Value.ToString)
    End With
```

Comment: why do you call Cancel method?

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to use ado's `NextRecordSet` and not use output parameter at all

```
if ((@iCountDistinctBanks > 1) or (@iCountDistinctBanks = 0))
    begin
        set @iOutDistinceBankCount = @iCountDistinctBanks 
        select @iOutDistinceBankCount as OutDistinceBankCount 
        select 0 where 0 = 1
    end

else
    begin
        set @iOutDistinceBankCount = 1;
        select @iOutDistinceBankCount as OutDistinceBankCount 

            select a.DCC_BANK_ID as DCC_BANK_ID
            from DEF a with(nolock)
            join ABC b with(nolock) on
            a.ROLEID = b.ROLEID
            where b.USERNAME = @szUserName and b.STATUS_ID = 2
    end

END
```

in code

get the first record set which is your parameter
then `rs = rs.NextRecordSet()` ... read your rows

performance: output parameter vs `select` really is not a consideration here